# Using Coredata to save Json dictionary

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

Im a newbie to Coredata , In my project i have to parse json from an API and i need to save the parsed json dictionary using core data .I have made a new Entity named Json and added a attribute of type String, But when i do like that its showing a error that  'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "information"; desired type = NSString

But i cannot choose a attribute type NSString , the following is the code i used to save json dictionary using core data . Please suggest me a solution for this.

```
let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if let res = response {

            print(res)
        }

        if let data = data {

            do {

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! NSDictionary

               let NewData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Json", into: context)

                NewData.setValue(json.value(forKey:"result")  , forKey:"information")

                do {

                    try context.save()
                    print("SAVED")
                }

                catch {

                    print(error)
                }

            }

            catch {

                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    session.resume()
```

My json data is the following

```
{

 "result": [


        {
            "category_name": "today"
        },

        {
            "category_name": "TechCrunch",
            "category_image": "1500899368.jpg"
        },

        {
            "category_name": "Science Daily",
            "category_image": "1500899358.jpg"
        },

        {
            "category_name": "ShowerThoughts",
            "category_image": "1500899351.jpg"
        },

        {
            "category_name": "BBC",
            "category_image": "1500899343.png"
        },


        {
            "category_name": "Goal.com",
            "category_image": "1500899336.jpg"
        },
        {
            "category_name": "Today I Learned",
            "category_image": "1500899329.jpg"
        },


        {
            "category_name": "Times Of India",
            "category_image": "1500899321.png"
        },


        {
            "category_name": "MIT Technology Review",
            "category_image": "1500899313.png"
        },


        {
            "category_name": "Business Insider",
            "category_image": "1500458239.jpg"
        },


        {
            "category_name": "coindesk",
            "category_image": "1500544039.jpg",
            "data": [
                {
                    "category_id": "34",
                    "news_id": "215",
                    "news_quote": "",
                    "title": "Bitcoin drama",
                    "image": "2017-07-20/1500544487.jpg",
                    "date": "2017-09-07 04:10:10"
                },


                {
                    "category_id": "34",
                    "news_id": "225",
                    "news_quote": "",
                    "title": "Bitcoin Price Surges",
                    "image": "2017-07-21/1500629251.jpg",
                    "date": "2017-09-07 04:10:10"
                },


                {
                    "category_id": "34",
                    "news_id": "229",
                    "news_quote": null,
                    "title": "Bitcoin Prices Gain",
                    "image": "2017-07-22/1500635952.jpg",
                    "date": "2017-09-07 04:10:10"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "response": {
        "status": "success",
        "status_code": 1,
        "message": "success"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the json that you are getting?

Comment: @ 3stud1ant3 Updated my Question

Comment: It seems that result is not a String , it is an array

Comment: @ 3stud1ant3  so what is the solution to save the json dictionary

Answer (score 2):

First of all **do not use Foundation `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift**.

The value for key `result` is an array of `[String:Any]` dictionaries. Use a loop to create new records and assign the category name to the `information` attribute.

```
...

do {

    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
    if let result = json["result"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        for category in result {
            let newData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Json", into: context)
            newData.information = category["category_name"] as! String
            // or if the entity is not a `NSManagedObject` subclass
            // newData.setValue(category["category_name"] as! String, forKey:"information")
        }

        try context.save()
        print("SAVED")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

- To save also the value to `category_image` you need a second attribute in the entity.
- To save the JSON in key `data` you need a second entity with a relationship to the first entity.

Some notes:

- Variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.
- The `options` parameter in the `JSONSerialization` line can be omitted.
- Save the context only once after the loop.
- Use only one `do catch` block.

Comment: @ vadian Thank you for your answer